# Rails 5 Action Mailer jpg is not transmitted properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send an email using ActionMailer on my local development environment. Everything's working fine, except the attachments.

In the following code block I attach the JPG file to an email, "Testbild.jpg", which has a size of 6,19KB. However, the receiver sees an email with a file of the same name that has a size of only 96 bytes.

```
def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    attachments['Testbild.jpg'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/Testbild.jpg")
    mail(to: @user.kontakt.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
end
```

Here is my ActionMailer Config in the development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3001 }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    user_name: "christian.henschel@xclirion.de",
    password: "************",
    domain: "xclirion.de",
    authentication: :plain,
    address: "smtp.xclirion.de",
    openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    port: 587
}
```

I found out that the 96 bytes of the received file are exactly the same as the first 96 bytes of my source file. The rest seems to be lost.

What goes wrong here? How can I force RoR to send the whole file?

Comment: Try this `attachments.inline['Testbild.jpg'] = File.read("#Rails.root}/public/images/Testbild.jpg")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your attachments hash as shown below:

```
def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    attachments['Testbild.jpg'] = File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/images/Testbild.jpg", 'rb'){|f| f.read}
    mail(to: @user.kontakt.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
end
```